# How do you get a count of the occurrence of a word in each of a large set of files in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to get the frequency of a particular word in several files.
This is what I wrote in the Unix shell:

```
find . -name "*.out" | xargs grep -i "search_string" | wc -l
```

The problem with this is giving me sum of all the frequencies of all the document. I want to get individual counts for each file. What is the best way to do this is shell?

Comment: Use `xargs grep -c "search_string"` without `wc` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name '*. out' -exec grep -ci "search_string" {} +
```

Comment: In some shells, you'll need a `\ ` before `{}` to avoid a syntax error from the shell...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: which shells?  (Not `bash`, `ksh`, `dash`, `zsh`, `csh`, ...)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Not entirely sure -- the bash manual page claims that `{` is reserved, and the find manual page claims that `{}` needs to be quoted or escaped "to protect them from expansion by the shell"

Answer (score 2):

**Using AWK**

```
 awk '/search_string/{a++}END{print a}' *.out
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this:

```
grep -c "search_string" *.out
```

Comment: only works for files in the current directory; not in any subdirectories.

Comment: @JohnZwinck's answer works better if the files are not all in the same dir. However OP didn't specify multiple dirs